# Groupby, pivot and return all columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` which looks like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    status  count
0   AA      PP      X       Y       13.1764     0   1.0
1   AA      PP      X       Y       12.145      0   1.0
2   AA      PP      X       Y       13.17       0   2.0
3   AA      PP      X       Y       23.5        0   2.0
4   AA      PP      X       Y       1100.4      0   2.0
5   AA      PP      X       Y       20.5        0   3.0
6   AA      PP      X       Y       1300.0      0   3.0
...
```

What I am trying to do?

1. Group by `col1`
2. Then group by `count`
3. Flatten the `col5` values and append to everything else

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
AA         col2 col3 col4 status count1 count2 count3
count  1.0  PP  X    Y     0     13.1764 12.145 NA 
       2.0  PP  X    Y     0     13.17   23.5   1100.4  
       3.0  PP  X    Y     0     20.5    1300.0 NA
```

I have seen a lot of `groupyby` and `pivot` questions and trust me I have tried a lot and wasted an hour but couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

If same values of all columns per groups like in sample data use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
g = df.groupby('count').cumcount()
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['col1','count','col2','col3','col4','status'],
                    columns=g, 
                    values='col5')
         .add_prefix('count')
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  col1  count col2 col3 col4  status   count0    count1  count2
0   AA    1.0   PP    X    Y       0  13.1764    12.145     NaN
1   AA    2.0   PP    X    Y       0  13.1700    23.500  1100.4
2   AA    3.0   PP    X    Y       0  20.5000  1300.000     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting this error: `Grouper for 'col5' not 1-dimensional`

Comment: @mlRocks - What is `print (df['col5'])` ?

Comment: Just a bunch of float values

Comment: @mlRocks - i think if test `print (df['col5'])` there are not 2 or 3 columns? because `col5` is duplicated?

Comment: You mean multiple columsn for `col5`?

Comment: @mlRocks - I try identify `Grouper for 'col5' not 1-dimensional`, reason should be some bad non stadard data or duplicated `col5`

Comment: Yeah I can see a bunch of `duplicated` values in  `col5`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207275/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mlrocks).